# Unexpected Cube movement when rotating camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently making an FPS game and I have some problems with camera movement. When I add a child object to the camera, and when I rotate the camera, the child object deforms.
I followed this tutorial to get my FPS movement. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAC8U9-dTZU/

[image]

Here is my camera movement script and my player movement one:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform player;

    void Update() {
        transform.position = player.transform.position;
    }
}
```

// Some stupid rigidbody based movement by Dani

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    //Assingables
    public Transform playerCam;
    public Transform orientation;
    
    //Other
    private Rigidbody rb;

    //Rotation and look
    private float xRotation;
    private float sensitivity = 150f;
    private float sensMultiplier = 1f;
    
    //Movement
    public float moveSpeed = 4500;
    public float maxSpeed = 20;
    public bool grounded;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    
    public float counterMovement = 0.175f;
    private float threshold = 0.01f;
    public float maxSlopeAngle = 35f;

    //Crouch & Slide
    private Vector3 crouchScale = new Vector3(1, 0.5f, 1);
    private Vector3 playerScale;
    public float slideForce = 400;
    public float slideCounterMovement = 0.2f;

    //Jumping
    private bool readyToJump = true;
    private float jumpCooldown = 0.25f;
    public float jumpForce = 550f;
    
    //Input
    float x, y;
    bool jumping, sprinting, crouching;
    
    //Sliding
    private Vector3 normalVector = Vector3.up;
    private Vector3 wallNormalVector;

    void Awake() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    
    void Start() {
        playerScale =  transform.localScale;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    
    private void FixedUpdate() {
        Movement();
    }

    private void Update() {
        MyInput();
        Look();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find user input. Should put this in its own class but im lazy
    /// </summary>
    private void MyInput() {
        x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        jumping = Input.GetButton("Jump");
        crouching = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl);
      
        //Crouching
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
            StartCrouch();
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl))
            StopCrouch();
    }

    private void StartCrouch() {
        transform.localScale = crouchScale;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 0.5f, transform.position.z);
        if (rb.velocity.magnitude > 0.5f) {
            if (grounded) {
                rb.AddForce(orientation.transform.forward * slideForce);
            }
        }
    }

    private void StopCrouch() {
        transform.localScale = playerScale;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 0.5f, transform.position.z);
    }

    private void Movement() {
        //Extra gravity
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 10);
        
        //Find actual velocity relative to where player is looking
        Vector2 mag = FindVelRelativeToLook();
        float xMag = mag.x, yMag = mag.y;

        //Counteract sliding and sloppy movement
        CounterMovement(x, y, mag);
        
        //If holding jump && ready to jump, then jump
        if (readyToJump && jumping) Jump();

        //Set max speed
        float maxSpeed = this.maxSpeed;
        
        //If sliding down a ramp, add force down so player stays grounded and also builds speed
        if (crouching && grounded && readyToJump) {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 3000);
            return;
        }
        
        //If speed is larger than maxspeed, cancel out the input so you don't go over max speed
        if (x > 0 && xMag > maxSpeed) x = 0;
        if (x < 0 && xMag < -maxSpeed) x = 0;
        if (y > 0 && yMag > maxSpeed) y = 0;
        if (y < 0 && yMag < -maxSpeed) y = 0;

        //Some multipliers
        float multiplier = 1f, multiplierV = 1f;
        
        // Movement in air
        if (!grounded) {
            multiplier = 0.5f;
            multiplierV = 0.5f;
        }
        
        // Movement while sliding
        if (grounded && crouching) multiplierV = 0f;

        //Apply forces to move player
        rb.AddForce(orientation.transform.forward * y * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * multiplier * multiplierV);
        rb.AddForce(orientation.transform.right * x * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * multiplier);
    }

    private void Jump() {
        if (grounded && readyToJump) {
            readyToJump = false;

            //Add jump forces
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce * 1.5f);
            rb.AddForce(normalVector * jumpForce * 0.5f);
            
            //If jumping while falling, reset y velocity.
            Vector3 vel = rb.velocity;
            if (rb.velocity.y < 0.5f)
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(vel.x, 0, vel.z);
            else if (rb.velocity.y > 0) 
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(vel.x, vel.y / 2, vel.z);
            
            Invoke(nameof(ResetJump), jumpCooldown);
        }
    }
    
    private void ResetJump() {
        readyToJump = true;
    }
    
    private float desiredX;
    private void Look() {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity * Time.fixedDeltaTime * sensMultiplier;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity * Time.fixedDeltaTime * sensMultiplier;

        //Find current look rotation
        Vector3 rot = playerCam.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
        desiredX = rot.y + mouseX;
        
        //Rotate, and also make sure we dont over- or under-rotate.
        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        //Perform the rotations
        playerCam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, desiredX, 0);
        orientation.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, desiredX, 0);
    }

    private void CounterMovement(float x, float y, Vector2 mag) {
        if (!grounded || jumping) return;

        //Slow down sliding
        if (crouching) {
            rb.AddForce(moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * -rb.velocity.normalized * slideCounterMovement);
            return;
        }

        //Counter movement
        if (Math.Abs(mag.x) > threshold && Math.Abs(x) < 0.05f || (mag.x < -threshold && x > 0) || (mag.x > threshold && x < 0)) {
            rb.AddForce(moveSpeed * orientation.transform.right * Time.deltaTime * -mag.x * counterMovement);
        }
        if (Math.Abs(mag.y) > threshold && Math.Abs(y) < 0.05f || (mag.y < -threshold && y > 0) || (mag.y > threshold && y < 0)) {
            rb.AddForce(moveSpeed * orientation.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * -mag.y * counterMovement);
        }
        
        //Limit diagonal running. This will also cause a full stop if sliding fast and un-crouching, so not optimal.
        if (Mathf.Sqrt((Mathf.Pow(rb.velocity.x, 2) + Mathf.Pow(rb.velocity.z, 2))) > maxSpeed) {
            float fallspeed = rb.velocity.y;
            Vector3 n = rb.velocity.normalized * maxSpeed;
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(n.x, fallspeed, n.z);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find the velocity relative to where the player is looking
    /// Useful for vectors calculations regarding movement and limiting movement
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Vector2 FindVelRelativeToLook() {
        float lookAngle = orientation.transform.eulerAngles.y;
        float moveAngle = Mathf.Atan2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        float u = Mathf.DeltaAngle(lookAngle, moveAngle);
        float v = 90 - u;

        float magnitue = rb.velocity.magnitude;
        float yMag = magnitue * Mathf.Cos(u * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        float xMag = magnitue * Mathf.Cos(v * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        
        return new Vector2(xMag, yMag);
    }

    private bool IsFloor(Vector3 v) {
        float angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, v);
        return angle < maxSlopeAngle;
    }

    private bool cancellingGrounded;
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Handle ground detection
    /// </summary>
    private void OnCollisionStay(Collision other) {
        //Make sure we are only checking for walkable layers
        int layer = other.gameObject.layer;
        if (whatIsGround != (whatIsGround | (1 << layer))) return;

        //Iterate through every collision in a physics update
        for (int i = 0; i < other.contactCount; i++) {
            Vector3 normal = other.contacts[i].normal;
            //FLOOR
            if (IsFloor(normal)) {
                grounded = true;
                cancellingGrounded = false;
                normalVector = normal;
                CancelInvoke(nameof(StopGrounded));
            }
        }

        //Invoke ground/wall cancel, since we can't check normals with CollisionExit
        float delay = 3f;
        if (!cancellingGrounded) {
            cancellingGrounded = true;
            Invoke(nameof(StopGrounded), Time.deltaTime * delay);
        }
    }

    private void StopGrounded() {
        grounded = false;
    }
    
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your player in CamerRotate the player which your camera is the parent of?

Comment: My camera is the child of a gameobject named cameraHolder, which contains the camera rotate script, which is the child of the player, which contains the player movement script

Comment: My best guess is that it is because the player rotates in its script, as well as the camera. If you want both to rotate through their own scripts the camera cannot be the child or the child of anything that is a child of the player. Try just having the camera as a child of the player without having the camera rotate script, it should rotate with the player.

Comment: Sure thing. I hope this helped. :)